# dyld[8243]: Symbol not found: (_nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_trailing_ws_validation) while trying php -v. PHP not working in mac intel

Tags: php, macos, dyld, nghttp2, icu4c

My php is not wokring in mac intel. This is what I get when I run php -v

```
➜  ~ php -v
dyld[8243]: Symbol not found: (_nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_trailing_ws_validation)
  Referenced from: '/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.87.0/lib/libcurl.4.dylib'
  Expected in: '/usr/local/Cellar/libnghttp2/1.47.0/lib/libnghttp2.14.dylib'
[1]    8243 abort      php -v
```

My first problem was My icu4c was 71 version and my php was looking for icu4c 70.1 version. So I have manually uninstall icu4c 71 and installed icu4c 70. Now I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of libcurl you have is looking for libnghttp2 but you don't have it on your system, reinstall both libnghttp2 and libcurl after making sure they're compatible with each other

Try (in a terminal near you)

```
brew install libnghttp2
```

Comment: Thank you. After running
`brew unpin icu4c` and `brew reinstall curl`
It solved my problem.